# Transition without loose data with Storyboard and Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a new project in Swift but i've a big (and dumb) problem.

I've three viewControllers:

1.- Call webservices, take JSON and pass this JSON to the second view

2.- Parsing data and put the data in the view (tableview and everything ok). At this view I go to other view with a button (to the view 3). I don't need pass nothing.

3.- I try to go back to view 2 but the view is empty because the data who posicioning at the tableview was pass from view 1.

I try with a lot of solutions:

- navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil) -> If i link the storyboard with a transition from view 3 to view 2, the view 2 is empty, if i don't link in storyboard -> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
- If i change "!" for "?" do nothing
- The same with every code i have been test.

My code is:

View 1 to view 2: (connected in the visual part of Storyboard (IB))

```
@IBAction func goRecibosPendientes(sender: UIButton) {

        let controllerVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recibos") as! TablaRecibosTableViewController

        controllerVC.initWithJSON(self.jsonReceived)
        self.presentViewController(controllerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

View 2 to View 3: (connected in the visual part of Storyboard (IB))

```
@IBAction func goToTablaProveedoresDeServicios(sender: UIButton) {

        let controllerVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("proveedoresDeServicios") as! TablaProveedoresDeServicios
        self.presentViewController(controllerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

View 3 to 2: I try every kinds of do that (every kinds i know, not EVERY kinds)

```
@IBAction func backPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        navigationController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can store "initWithJSON(self.jsonReceived)" in Global Veriable. You can take Global Veriable in AppDelegate or in Model class.

Comment: Thanks Pavan, that was my first idea, but in every "swift best practices" i read that this solution is not recomendable and not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NavigationController` than try to `push` a view controller it will remains your previous view in stack.

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(controllerVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: If i use navigationController.pushViewController(controllerVC, animated:true), the compiles says: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @krayan please write your code. so i can do something.